# ActiveJob does not use sidekiq in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have upgraded my app to rails version 4.2.0.rc2. I try to use sidekiq as active_job backend. It works OK in development environment, but in production environment it uses Inline(mailers) instead of Sidekiq.

```
# config/initializers/active_job.rb 
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
end
```

rails sever -e development

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID:...) to Sidekiq(mailers)
```

rails sever -e production

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID:...) to Inline(mailers)
```

On console

```
$ rails c -e production
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.0.rc2)
[1] pry(main)> Rails.configuration.active_job.queue_adapter
=> :sidekiq
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution. Instead of initializer put your queue_adapter config to application config.

```
# config/application.rb
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - not sure why the sidekiq doco says to put it in an initializer when that doesn't seem to work.